# In R, why is there awkward output in the legend when I am using paste() instead of c() in addition to pretty10exp()?

Tags: r, plot, legend

I'm trying to make the legend of this plot pretty, so I need there the be an actual superscript, which is why I am using the pretty10exp() function from the sfsmisc library. It works when I use the c() function.

However, I am also trying to keep the string and the scientific notation number on the same line. The legend() is broken into two lines, which I think is due to c(). I thought I could use paste(), but for some reason the output is now incorrect.

```
plot(1:12)
pVal <- 4
legend("topright", legend = c("P value:", sfsmisc::pretty10exp(pVal)), cex = 1.5)

legend("topright", legend = paste("P value:", sfsmisc::pretty10exp(pVal)), cex = 1.5)
```

pVal being an arbitrary number represented in scientific notation. The second line results in output like this: `"P value: (significand) %*% 10^-4"`. The first line also doesn't give me what I want. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `c()` won't work as it will create a length 2 character vector. As for making an 'actual superscript', try using the much simpler [`plotmath`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html), although I don't know if you think that is pretty enough.

Comment: I can't use plotmath, because the number in scientific notation is saved in a variable. I tried for a while unsuccessfully. Also I don't know what you mean create a length 2 character vector?

Comment: It would help if you provided a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to test with. Make sure all variables and functions are defined.

Comment: Well, any example will work. I should have explained what pVal is, though. It's just an arbitrary number in scientific notation.

Comment: Here is an example: plot(1:12); pVal <- 4; and try one of the following lines after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pretty10exp` returns an expression which allows it to use the `?plotmath` features for making nice looking numbers. When working with expressions, you can't just paste values in like strings. You need to manipulate them with a special set of functions. One such function is `substitute`. You can do

```
plot(1:12)
pVal <- 4
legend("topright", cex = 1.5, 
    legend = substitute("P value: "*x, list(x=sfsmisc::pretty10exp(pVal)[[1]])) )
```

We use `substitute()` to take the value contained in the expression from `pretty10exp` and prefix it with the label you want. (We use `*` to concatenate rather than `paste()` since `plotmath` allows it)

[image]

Comment: This is too complicated. Just write the whole expression with bquote which lets you use a value from a variable in it. No need for a package.

Comment: How would you use bquote? I tried it, but it doesn't work when the argument  is a variable. You'd have to hard code the number in.

Comment: @Bob I suggest reading the documentation. I might write an answer later.

Comment: @Roland I still think it's easier to modify the expression rather than recode the logic in pretty10exp. I guess if you wanted to support fewer features than maybe it wouldn't be so bad but I didn't want to bother with recreating the formatting code.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

```
fun <- function(text, pVal) {
  y <- floor(log10(pVal))
  x <- pVal / 10^y
  bquote(.(text)*":" ~ .(x) %.% 10 ^ .(y))
}

plot.new()
text(0.5,0.7,fun("P value", 0.4))
text(0.5, 0.3, fun("P value", signif(1/pi, 1)))
```

[image: resulting plot]

No package is needed.